# Integrate login page to hugo

Tags: javascript, hugo

I will be posting links on my each post. Is there something I can do so that a visited can only see those links if he is logged in and how to create a login.html to be configured with Hugo?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hugo is a Static websit generator. I'm not really sure how you expect to create a login system within hugo. If I misunderstood your questions please let me know.

Posted as answer because I don't have enough rep for comment yet.

Comment: I meant through any external source.